# After add index to MySQL table the table did not open

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this table

```
id     name image
1      aa   x.png
2      bb   cc.png
.
.
102145 fgf  rrr.png
```

The table have more than 102K rows.

After add index to name the process hanged then could not open the table and even can not select from it any row.

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: You are using phpmyadmin??

Comment: sounds like your table was damaged, take help from this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-table-maintenance.html

Comment: SQL Manager 2010 for mysql.

Comment: Try this command `repair table table_name quick`

Comment: Anything useful in the file `mysqld.err` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by restarting mysql server.